# Finding the largest vector inside a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, find, cell-array, submatrix

I am trying to find the largest vector inside a matrix compound by vectors with MATLAB, however I am having some difficulties, so I would be very thankful if someone help me. I have this:

The matrix paths (solution of a Dijkstra function), which is a 1000x1000 matrix, whose values are vectors of 1 row and different number of columns (when the columns are bigger than 10, the values appear as "1x11 double, 1x12 double, etc"). The matrix paths have this form:

```
         1                   2                           3 ....
  1      1                   <1x20 double>              <1x16 double>
  2    <1x20 double>         2                          [2,870,183,492,641,863,611,3]
  3    <1x16 double>     [3,611,863,641,492,183,870,2]   3   
  4    <1x25 double>         <1x12 double>               <1x14 double>
  .
  .
  .
```

At first I thought in just finding the largest vector in the matrix by

```
B = max(length(paths))
```

However MATLAB returns B = 1000, value which is feasible, but not likely. When trying to find out the position of the vector by using:

```
[row,column] = find(length(paths) == B)
```

MATLAB returns row = 1, column = 1, which for sure is wrong... I have thought that maybe is a problem of how MATLAB takes the data. It is like it doesn't consider the entries of the matrix as vectors, because when I enter:

```
   length(paths(3,2))
```

It returns me 1, but it should return 8 as I understand, also when introducing:

```
    paths(3,2)
```

It returns  `[1x8 double]` but I expect to see the whole vector. I don't know what to do, maybe a "for" loop, I really do not know if MATLAB takes the data of the matrix as vectors or as simple double values.

Comment: what do you get when you run `class(paths)` ?

Comment: cells, So, it is a matrix of cells.. but it seems as doubles values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cell with the largest vector can be found using `cellfun` and `numel` to get the number of elements in each numeric matrix stored in the cells of `paths`:

```
vecLens = cellfun(@numel,paths);
[maxLen,im] = max(vecLens(:));
[rowMax,colMax] = ind2sub(size(vecLens),im)
```

This gets a 1000x1000 numeric matrix `vecLens` containing the sizes, `max` gets the linear index of the largest element, and `ind2sub` translates that to row,column indexes.

A note on `length`: It gives you the size of the largest dimension. The size of `paths` is 1000x1000, so `length(paths)` is 1000. My advice is, Don't ever use `length`. Use `size`, specifying the dimension you want.

---

If multiple vectors are the same length, you get the first one with the above approach.  To get all of them (starting after the `max` command):

```
maxMask = vecLens==maxLen;
if nnz(maxMask)>1,
    [rowMax,colMax] = find(maxMask);
else
    [rowMax,colMax] = ind2sub(size(vecLens),im)
end
```

or just

```
[rowMax,colMax] = find(vecLens==maxLen);
```

Comment: I would also explain that the `numel` function gives the number of elements of a matrix. When you call it with `cellfun`, it will call `numel` for each matrix inside `paths` cell array. The result will be a 1000x1000 matrix where `vecLens(r,c)` contains the length of the path at `paths(r,c)`.

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro Thanks for the suggestions.  Updated.

Comment: Thank you both, your responses are very helpful :D

Comment: Good advice about `length`! +1

Comment: @user2822577 Also note that if there are multiple cells with the same largest length, the first solution just gives the first instance. To get all, see the added solution in my answer.

Comment: Yup, in this case there is just one solution, but it is very useful, I am glad there are people like you in the world ;)